# Rearranging an inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

We are given that $x > y \geq 0$ and we know $y > x/2$. I'd like to show that $x -y < x/2$?

Here's where I've attempted so far and I am getting stuck.

$x > y > x/2$

$x - y > 0 > x/2 - y$ (Now I'm stuck)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We keep one eye on what we want to show.

We have 
$$y \gt x/2.$$

Multiply both sides by $-1$. Remember this **reverses** the inequality.
We get
$$-y \lt -x/2.$$
Add $x$ to both sides. We get
$$x+(-y)\lt x+(-x/2).$$
This can be rewritten as
$$x-y\lt x-x/2=x/2.$$

Answer (score 2):

$x<2y$ from conditions

$x+x<2y+x$ add $x$ on both sides

$2x<2y+x$ divide by $2$

$x<y+x/2$ or equivalently

$x-y<x/2$